# Creating a new directory in a MATLAB GUI

Tags: matlab, matlab-guide

I know that to create a new folder is `mkdir`. But I was wondering if there was a way that I could setup a GUI so that it would create a new folder with the name of the subject by having a window within the GUI where someone can name type in the subject name then create a folder by a push button. Still new to creating GUIs. I suppose it would take some combination of Edit Text and a Push Button. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You are right, you can create an edit button (e.g. `hed = uicontrol('Style','edit')`) and a pushbutton (e.g. `hpush = uicontrol('style','pushbutton')`) and then define the `pushbutton`'s `ButtonDownFcn` callback to get the `'String'` from `hed` and call `mkdir`.  I'd show an example if you would present some code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An alternative would be set the pushbutton-callback so something along this, similar to a "save as..." button in other applications:

```
function pushbutton_callback(hObject, evt, handles)
    directory = uigetdir(pwd, 'Select Directory');
    if ischar(directory)
        set(handles.textfield, 'String', directory);
    end
```

This way the user is prompted by a proper windows dialog to select a folder.
This dialog also enables the user the create a new folder that is then inserted into your textfield.
This is kind of the other way round then the original approach, but is the more common way for use-cases such as "select the directory where to save xxx".

Comment: How could you set it up to cd into the folder you just made because it doesnt seem to do that. Im sorry if that seems like a dumb question

Comment: Just add `cd(directory);`  after `set(handles.textfield, 'String', directory);`

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you have a Text Edit Box named 'TargetDirName_et', and a Push Button named 'CreateDir_pb' try the following:

In your code for the 'CreateDir_pb' push button callback:

```
function CreateDir_pb_Callback(hObject, eventdata, handles)
% hObject    handle to CreateDir_pb (see GCBO)
% eventdata  reserved - to be defined in a future version of MATLAB
% handles    structure with handles and user data (see GUIDATA)
dirString= get(handles.TargetDirName_et,'String');
mkdir(dirString);
```